# recalculating folds in vim without applying foldlevel

Tags: vim, neovim, folding

I'm trying to set up neovim as a python IDE and I'm having some trouble making folding work like I want it to.

My setup:
NVIM 0.4.3
`Plug 'Konfekt/FastFold'`
`Plug 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'`
`nnoremap <space> za` to toggle a fold with spacebar

My issue is that SimpylFold does not seem to recalculate folds as I edit a file in `insert` mode. So any function or class I add to a file with insert mode will just say `E490: No fold found`. Curiously, if I select the lines I've added, delete them and undo, the folds are then correctly recognized. Pasting in a function in `normal` mode also correctly detects the new fold. So the issue seems to only appear when adding lines in `insert` mode.

Here's what I know so far:

- I've tried `:set foldmethod=indent` but it falls short of the functionality I'm looking for.
- `zx` forces recalculate on folds. This does work, but the problem is it reapplies `foldlevel` to the whole buffer, which will undo all the manual fold toggles I've done with space. Couldn't find anything in the documentation about recalculating folds without reapplying `foldlevel`

From what I can gather, each line in vim has a `foldlevel` which determines what fold level that line belongs to.. for example all unindented lines in python would have `foldlevel=0`, Then the entire buffer *also* has a foldlevel, which determines which levels are actually folded.. so if the buffer's `foldlevel` is set to 1, then all lines with `foldlevel` of 1 or more would be folded.
the `za` command which im using to toggle a specific fold manually seems to operate on a layer separate from all this `foldlevel` stuff, and when `zx` is used to recalculate folds, all manual folds/unfolds from `za` are lost

Anyways, please correct me if I'm wrong, I just switched to linux (and with it, vim) a couple weeks ago, so I'm far from what you'd consider an expert.

Comment: I have this issue too, did you find a solution?

Comment: nope, I've taken to just relying less on folds in my workflow and quietly muttering to myself whenever some vim user says "vim can do anything"

Comment: I have actually found a solution. It's kind of a hack, but it works. Put this in your .vimrc (or init.vim): `au InsertLeave,TextChanged *.py set foldmethod=expr`. It just sets the fold method every time you leave insert mode or change text in normal mode (with dd, yy p, etc), which also forces it to recalculate the folds. It works much better than what may people recommend, which is just running :e! every time, or zx, which re-applies foldleve, as you stated. It may cause some lag when leaving insert mode, but I haven't noticed any.

Comment: Did this work for you? If it does I can add it as an answer.

Comment: FastFold disables the recomputation of folds in insert mode. In particular, it overrides all manual folds. Therefore, not loading FastFold should resolve your issue.